# Выполнить replace() в заданной области textarea

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите новичку, пожалуйста, как выполнить replace() в заданной области textarea?

К примеру, нужно заменить **'я'** на **'z'** в textarea, но только те **'я'**, которые находятся внутри [m]*здесь*[/m], при этом возле **'я'** внутри **[m][/m]** есть и другие символы.

Как заменять все **'я'** на **'z'** в textarea сразу после ввода (onkeyup=""), разобрался

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyReplace(obj)
{   obj=document.getElementById('abcd');
    var str=obj.value;
    obj.value = str.replace('я', 'z');
}
</script>

<textarea id="abcd" onkeyup="MyReplace(this)" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Регуляркой вырвать нужные куски, сделать замену реплейсом и вернуть обратно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re= /\[m\]((.(?!\[\/m\]))*.)\[\/m\]/ig;
translit= function(text, group1) {
    // функция транслитерации. Найти в интернете легко. Для примера возвращает не транслитерацию, а верхний регистр.
    return group1.toUpperCase();
};
test="other [m] test it! [/m] other";
alert(test.replace(re, translit));
```

Результат:

```
other TEST IT! other
```

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо!
Пытаюсь применить Вашу подсказку для своей функции (исправление раскладки клавиатуры), но не получается, к сожалению.

Если у Вас будет время, взгляните, пожалуйста
http://learn.javascript.ru/play/YuwQGb

Исправлять раскладку клавиатуры во время ввода во всей textarea получилось, но не могу сделать это исправление только внутри [m][/m].

Comment: Изменил Ваш [образец]( http://learn.javascript.ru/play/8nzPnc) по этой ссылке откройте untitled.js вкладку и увидите готовый образчик. Введите текст в псевдо тэге и увидите результат.

Comment: Благодарю!
Только при корректировке удаляются  псевдо тэги [m][/m] и последний символ их содержимого, но разобрался, как исправить:

- окаймил этими тэгами group1 в return correctLayout(group1);
- переместил в /\[m\]((.(?!\[\/m\]))+).\[\/m\]/ig вторую точку влево сразу за круглую скобку.
http://learn.javascript.ru/play/adi68b
Ещё, если в [m][/m] только один символ, то он не корректируется, что не могу исправить.

Comment: Верно. Поправил регулярку с учетом замечаний.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а не могли бы написать регулярку здесь, а то в отладчике http://learn.javascript.ru/play какой-то глюк произошёл.

Comment: @aaron, в ответе смотрите. Я в нем и написал с исправлением.

Comment: Простите, в каком ответе?

Comment: Чуть выше по тексту. Я кстати привел необоснованно сложное выражение, по привычке начал строить выражение, которое может учитывать экранирование `\[`. Для простых целей, это конечно же излишне.  
Вот такое выражение успешно со всем справится:  

     re= /\[m\](.*?)\[\/m\]/ig;

Comment: Неудивительно, что за ответ не дали ни одного балла. Вопрос стоял четко, в заданной области, а не парсить весь текст там где надо и не надо. Сначала нужно было привести пример создания области createRange, с которой уже и нужно будет работать. Сколько лет прошло, а ответа и нет))

Comment: В ответе показана техника каскадного спуска. Никто не запрещает внутри каскада сделать createRange или любые другие действия. Как бы Вы решили задачу?